# Can no longer build an old project in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, build, mono, xamarin

I have an old project that used to build

However I have recently tried rebuilding since a xamarin update it and I get an error message

> The name 'Build' does not exist within the current context.

[image: build not exist]

I've tried building it with different versions of the .net framework

[image: options]

but none of these have worked.

I have also noticed the warning message

> Warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"
>   property to true in the project file.

It looks like I might be building it with the wrong assembly version.

---

**EDIT**

I've checked the GTK version and there is only one option in my case.
Version 2.12

[image: GTK Version]

---

**EDIT**

I've just tried restoring my code from version control.

My project will build! ... But I have not really fixed the problem since I get the following runtime error.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
```

Which tells me that I haven't built it with libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll.

---

**EDIT**

I've just created a simple test program after reinstalling Xamarin

[image: Mono Test]

When I built it the first time I get the same message about "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"

When I built it again I get a different error message.

[image: Error]

System.DllNotFoundException

I'm back to not being able to find libgtk

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did you check the GTK# version?

Comment: I wonder if I could have damaged my installation with nuget

Comment: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11837/cross-platform-assembly-nightmare-can-somebody-please-help

Comment: I've tried reinstalling xamarin, no success. I've also tried building with visual studio: I get the same System.DllNotFoundException

Comment: It's interesting that when I build with visual studio I get a runtime error. But when I build with xamarin I get a compile time error.

Comment: The runtime error occurs in Application.Init ();

Comment: Since this error occurs for a new project, could this be a bug in xamarin?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my machine. Not a typical bug then.

Comment: Does anyone know how to fully uninstall xamarin?

Comment: To fully uninstall, go to Programs and uninstall everything with Xamarin in its name. That should be enough for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got it working. Here's what I did

I uninstalled all xamarin, mono and GTK programs from windows using the windows control panel.

Removed all registry entries I could find.

Manually deleted the remaining program files from my hard drive.

Went and downloaded the latest versions of GTK and mono and .net. Reinstalled and rebooted.

Copied the gtk files into my program directory and everything worked.

[image: gtk]

I'm not sure which of these steps may have helped.